# How to make a static, locally accessible html table sortable?

Tags: python, html, sorting

I have a static html file that looks like

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>.79</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bread</td>
      <td>2.29</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Corn</td>
      <td>.89</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a static file generated programatically via python and only has to be accessible locally.  How can I make the columns sortable from the html page?

Comment: Are you able to edit the python code?

Comment: Yes, I am able to edit the python code (in any way)

Comment: I suggest generating an array with subarrays for each item, then sorting it in python, then generating the table via jQuery or vanilla JS. LMK if you want me to write some code to explain what I mean

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified... I am hoping for this table to be sortable from the html page itself, as opposed to only on the backend

Comment: Look into using a grid component such as the one available at https://dhtmlx.com/. They have a freebie that might do the trick. But what does this have to do with Python? Who cares where it came from?

Comment: I would suggest to use javascript. Check the examples in w3schools. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp